# Themes appear broken in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, themes

For some reason, Ambiance and Radiance themese (including Communitheme from PPA) appear broken in Ubuntu 18.04.

My installation is from when 18.04 was released and everything looked and worked fine until now.

Right now Ambiance theme looks like this;

[image]

Here's how settings window looks (notice the scrollbar on hover);

[image]

I tried reinstall `light-themes` as well as `ubuntu-desktop` package, but it doesn't help.